# React-Native component updates when I save changes, and not upon starting. [Firebase, useEffect]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm still a rookie programmer so hopefully my code is understandable.

I have a Firestore DB, I have no problems getting access to the data stored, the problem is with React components or Expo.

This problem occurs in various parts of my software, I'm just going to include one (If you guys help me to solve it, I think I would be able to solve the others)

This is my auth flow:

LoginForm.js (Creates User with Email and Pass on Firebase) -> AddExtraInfo (Save some profile data) -> ProfileInfoWorker (Save some extra data) -> Account (If the user is logged goes to UserGuest otherwhise to UserLogged) -> UserLogged (Gets the info) -> InfoUser(The component which shows the info)

```
  //  UserLogged.js
  export default function UserLogged(props) {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const [perfilData, setPerfilData] = useState("");

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    setUserInfo(user);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      setLoading(true);
      let ref = db.collection("perfil-final");
      let query = ref
        .where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No matching documents.");
            return;
          }
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            setPerfilData(doc.data());
          });
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });
    }
  }, []); 
   return (
    <View style={styles.viewUserInfo}>
      {userInfo && (
        <InfoUser
          userInfo={userInfo}
          perfilData={perfilData}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

And here I print the info

```
//InfoUser.js
export default function InfoUser(props) {
  const {
    userInfo: { uid, displayName, email },
    perfilData,
  }
   return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>
          {displayName ? displayName : "Anonymous"}
        </Text>
        <Text>{email ? email : "Anonymous"}</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}
```

The thing is, when I get to the UserLogged screen, It loads "Anonymous", but if I press CTRL + S on my code editor, and get the refreshing alert, I get the correct data. What is happening?
I assume my code is getting null at first so it's not showing the data, but when It changes, why it doesn't update?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

EDIT:

```
// RegisterForm.js
export default function RegisterForm(props) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(defaultFormValue());

  const onChange = (e, type) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [type]: e.nativeEvent.text });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    //.. here I validate empty fields and then..
    setLoading(true);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email, formData.password)
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        navigation.navigate("extrainfo");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log("Email already on use");
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.formContainer}>
      <Input
        placeholder="Email"
        containerStyle={styles.inputForm}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "email")}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Password"
        containerStyle={styles.inputForm}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "password")}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={showPassword ? false : true}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Repeat Password"
        containerStyle={styles.inputForm}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "repeatPassword")}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={showRepeatPassword ? false : true}
      />
      <Button
        title="Join"
        containerStyle={styles.btnRegisterForm}
        buttonStyle={styles.btnRegister}
        onPress={onSubmit}
      />
      <Loading isVisible={loading} text="Making account..." />
    </View>
  );
}
function defaultFormValue() {
  return {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    repeatPassword: "",
  };
}
```

Here I redirect when the user press on the account tab, if the user is logged goes to UserLogged, if not goes to the UserLogged screen.

```
//Account.js
export default function Account() {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(null);
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    !user ? setLogin(false) : setLogin(true);
  });

  if (login === null) return <Loading isVisible={true} text="Cargando..." />;

  return login ? <UserLogged /> : <UserGuest />;
}
```

And here I'm using React Navigation, trying to get the userType first, in order to show some tabs if the user is a worker, and other tab if the user is a client.

```
//Navigation.js
export default function Navigation(props) {
  const [userType, setUserType] = useState("");
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState("")
  const [nombreRuta, setNombreRuta] = useState("Solicitudes");
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(null);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    !user ? setLogin(false) : setLogin(true);
    if (!user) {
    userType("");
    }else{
    setUserInfo(user);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    if (login) {
      let perfilRef = db.collection("perfiles");
      perfilRef
        .where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No matching documents.");
            return;
          }
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            if (isSubscribed) {
              setTipoUsuario(doc.data().userType);
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });
    }
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [userInfo]); //Tried with: login and userType

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="requests"
        tabBarOptions={{
          inactiveTintColor: "#646464",
          activeTintColor: "#F7931C",
        }}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({ 
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => screenOptions(route, color),
        })}
      >
        {userType == "worker" && (
          <Tab.Screen
            name="solicitudesworker"
            component={RequestsWorkerStack}
            options={{ title: "Requests" }}
          ></Tab.Screen>
        )}
        {userType == "client" && (
          <Tab.Screen
            name="restaurants"
            component={RequestsStack}
            options={{ title: "Requests" }}
          ></Tab.Screen>
        )}

        <Tab.Screen
          name="topworkers"
          component={topworkers}
          options={{ title: "Top Workers" }}
        ></Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="search"
          component={SearchStack}
          options={{ title: "Search" }}
        ></Tab.Screen>

        <Tab.Screen
          name="account"
          component={AccountStack}
          options={{ title: "Account" }}
        ></Tab.Screen>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is your useEffect is being called on the mount of the component and then never called again.

This is because using useEffect with no dependancy array only calls the function once. It's being called before the userInfo state has chance to update and therefore, its all ways null. (When you hot reload it forces useEffect to be called. This doesn't happen in production).

You need to pass userInfo into the dependency array of useEffect. This way when the userInfo state is update the useEffect will be called again.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (userInfo) {
  setLoading(true);
  let ref = db.collection("perfil-final");
  let query = ref
    .where("userId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
        return;
      }
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setPerfilData(doc.data());
      });
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
}
}, [userInfo]);
```

Let me know where this gets you.

Comment: Still the same, just loads the info when I hot reload. Also, this only happens when I create a new user, and I'm redirected to the UserLogged screen, when I log out, and then sign in, the data loads fine.

Comment: Please can you update your answer with the LoginForm.js and any other code you think is relevant to this flow as it sounds like theres some state not updating somewhere